# What are the requirements for a manifest file is valid for the player DASH JS?

Tags: mpeg-dash, mpd

I read this document http://dashif.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/DASH-IF-Conformance-Software-v0.9.pdf to know what are the rules that must accomplish a MPD file.

The manifest was validated with http://dashif.org/conformance.html, and the result was successful. But the player DASH-JS (http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.4.0/samples/dash-if-reference-player/) doesn't do anything when I try to load it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011" type="static" minBufferTime="PT2S" mediaPresentationDuration="PT53250S">
<Period>
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="720" maxHeight="576" maxFrameRate="24" par="5:4" startWithSAP="1">
  <ContentComponent id="1" contentType="video"/>
    <SegmentTemplate presentationTimeOffset="13333333" timescale="10000000" initialization="seg_$RepresentationID$_init.mp4" media="seg_$RepresentationID$_t$Time$.mp4">
      <SegmentTimeline>
        <S d="50000000" t="13333333" r="117"/>
      </SegmentTimeline>
    </SegmentTemplate>
    <Representation id="video_0" bandwidth="1700000" mimeType="video/mp4" width="720" height="576" frameRate="24" sar="1:1" codecs="avc1.64001E"/>
    <Representation id="video_1" bandwidth="760000" mimeType="video/mp4" width="720" height="576" frameRate="24" sar="1:1" codecs="avc1.64001E"/>
    <Representation id="video_2" bandwidth="580000" mimeType="video/mp4" width="720" height="576" frameRate="24" sar="1:1" codecs="avc1.64001E"/>
    <Representation id="video_3" bandwidth="220000" mimeType="video/mp4" width="720" height="576" frameRate="24" sar="1:1" codecs="avc1.64001E"/>
    <Representation id="video_4" bandwidth="140000" mimeType="video/mp4" width="720" height="576" frameRate="24" sar="1:1" codecs="avc1.64001E"/>
  </AdaptationSet>
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" lang="und">
  <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="1"/>
  <ContentComponent id="1" contentType="audio"/>
    <SegmentTemplate presentationTimeOffset="13786666" timescale="10000000" initialization="seg_$RepresentationID$_init.mp4" media="seg_$RepresentationID$_t$Time$.mp4">
      <SegmentTimeline>
        <S d="52693333" t="13786666"/>
        <S d="53333333" t="66480000"/>
        <S d="53120000" t="119813333" r="1"/>
        <S d="51413333" t="226053333"/>
        <S d="52693333" t="277466666" r="1"/>
        <S d="53333333" t="382853333"/>
        <S d="53760000" t="436186666"/>
        <S d="53333333" t="489946666"/>
        <S d="52693333" t="543280000"/>
        <S d="52266666" t="595973333"/>
        <S d="52480000" t="648240000"/>
        <S d="53333333" t="700720000"/>
        <S d="52480000" t="754053333"/>
        <S d="52693333" t="806533333"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="859226666"/>
        <S d="51200000" t="912133333"/>
        <S d="53760000" t="963333333"/>
        <S d="52053333" t="1017093333"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="1069146666"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="1122053333"/>
        <S d="52053333" t="1175600000"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="1227653333"/>
        <S d="51840000" t="1280560000"/>
        <S d="52693333" t="1332400000"/>
        <S d="53760000" t="1385093333"/>
        <S d="52480000" t="1438853333"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="1491333333" r="1"/>
        <S d="54186666" t="1597146666"/>
        <S d="53760000" t="1651333333"/>
        <S d="51413333" t="1705093333"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="1756506666"/>
        <S d="53760000" t="1810053333"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="1863813333"/>
        <S d="53333333" t="1917360000"/>
        <S d="52053333" t="1970693333"/>
        <S d="53760000" t="2022746666"/>
        <S d="53333333" t="2076506666" r="1"/>
        <S d="52266666" t="2183173333"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="2235440000"/>
        <S d="53973333" t="2288346666"/>
        <S d="53120000" t="2342320000" r="1"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="2448560000"/>
        <S d="53333333" t="2502106666"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="2555440000"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="2608346666"/>
        <S d="52693333" t="2661893333"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="2714586666"/>
        <S d="51413333" t="2767493333"/>
        <S d="52693333" t="2818906666"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="2871600000"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="2924506666"/>
        <S d="51413333" t="2978053333"/>
        <S d="52266666" t="3029466666"/>
        <S d="51413333" t="3081733333"/>
        <S d="53760000" t="3133146666"/>
        <S d="51626666" t="3186906666"/>
        <S d="51840000" t="3238533333"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="3290373333"/>
        <S d="53120000" t="3343280000"/>
        <S d="52480000" t="3396400000"/>
        <S d="51413333" t="3448880000"/>
        <S d="53120000" t="3500293333"/>
        <S d="52266666" t="3553413333"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="3605680000"/>
        <S d="51840000" t="3659226666"/>
        <S d="53120000" t="3711066666"/>
        <S d="51413333" t="3764186666"/>
        <S d="51626666" t="3815600000"/>
        <S d="52693333" t="3867226666"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="3919920000"/>
        <S d="53120000" t="3973466666"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="4026586666"/>
        <S d="52053333" t="4079493333"/>
        <S d="54186666" t="4131546666"/>
        <S d="52053333" t="4185733333"/>
        <S d="53333333" t="4237786666"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="4291120000"/>
        <S d="52693333" t="4344026666"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="4396720000"/>
        <S d="52266666" t="4450266666"/>
        <S d="53120000" t="4502533333"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="4555653333"/>
        <S d="52053333" t="4608560000"/>
        <S d="53333333" t="4660613333" r="1"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="4767280000"/>
        <S d="53333333" t="4820826666"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="4874160000"/>
        <S d="53760000" t="4927066666"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="4980826666"/>
        <S d="53760000" t="5034373333"/>
        <S d="51840000" t="5088133333"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="5139973333"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="5193520000"/>
        <S d="53333333" t="5246426666" r="1"/>
        <S d="53973333" t="5353093333"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="5407066666"/>
        <S d="53120000" t="5460613333"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="5513733333"/>
        <S d="53120000" t="5566640000"/>
        <S d="53333333" t="5619760000" r="1"/>
        <S d="53546666" t="5726426666"/>
        <S d="52480000" t="5779973333"/>
        <S d="52906666" t="5832453333"/>
      </SegmentTimeline>
    </SegmentTemplate>
    <Representation id="audio257_0" bandwidth="160000" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2"/>
    <Representation id="audio257_1" bandwidth="160000" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2"/>
    <Representation id="audio257_2" bandwidth="140000" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2"/>
    <Representation id="audio257_3" bandwidth="120000" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2"/>
    <Representation id="audio257_4" bandwidth="100000" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2"/>
  </AdaptationSet>
</Period>
</MPD>
```

I appreciate any idea.

Thank you!

Comment: Dash.js is very verbose on the JS console, I suggest you check over there.

Comment: I know that this topic is very old, but I would suggest to go to the Network tab of the Debugger console in your web browser and see if the DASH-JS player is trying to download any segments/initialization files and what is the status of the download process.